# ERROR node_modules/@nebular/theme/index"' has no exported member 'NbWindowModule'

Tags: angular, mean-stack, ngx-admin

I am implementing a mean stack project using ngx- admin template. There I want to open a window by clicking a button in header component. For that I used 'NbWindowService '. I imported 'NbWindowModule' into the module from '@nebular/theme'. But it gives the following error.

**'ERROR in src/app/@theme/theme.module.ts(22,3): error TS2305: Module '"E:/ProjectName/node_modules/@nebular/theme/index"' has no exported member 'NbWindowModule'.'**

Then I installed npm again. But the problem is still same. Can anyone help me in this problem?